# Understanding and updating the gun user alias system

Tags: javascript, authentication, gun

On the gun `alias` system:

Is it like a phone book (public key book) where every user could have a different name for each key?

Is it stored in a user's user space, or is there some kind of local dict, or is it more of a global/universe thing?

---

There seems to be two ways to initialise a user:

**1:** via an alias and password, e.g.

```
let eve = gun.user().auth('Eve' ,'password123')
```

*How do you recover the public key for `eve`?*

Here's what I have but is seems like there'd be a better way:

```
let userObj
let eve= gun.user().auth('Eve' ,'password456',(u)=>{userObj = u})
let evePub = userObj.put.pub // or eve._.put.pub
```

---

**2:** via SEA pair, e.g.

```
let bob = await SEA.pair();
await gun.user().auth(bob)
```

*How do you set an alias for `bob`?*

Perhaps I have to set [`SEA.name`](https://github.com/amark/gun/blob/a092f5a725c7b0e38e653d53400f62adc7e65fd7/sea/auth.js#L133) or something to do with `~@` in the user space, but I'm not sure..

Answer (score 0):

1. To get the public key for user `eve` use the call back function:

```
    let pub =  await new Promise (res => user.auth('Eve' ,'password123',ack => 
    { 
        if (!ack.err) {
           res(ack.put.pub)
        } 
        else {
           res(ack.err)
        }
    }))
```

2. The alias is set in the `~@<alias>` property of the `~publicKeyOfUser` node, like [this](https://github.com/amark/gun/blob/5df08f91cb2959deb36c0f4f85c0e537ad103e0c/sea/create.js#L73):

```
    let link = {};
    let alias = 'bob'
    link['~'+bob.pub] = {'#': '~'+bob.pub};
    gun.get('~'+bob.pub).get('~@'+alias).put(link)
```

Comment: hey @lee is it working for you when you search user using alias?
When i try to search using that aias, I am not getting user's node when user is created using SEA.pair();

Comment: @DhavalJavia I don't know. Why not ask a new question with an example?